# Get onload hidden field value using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to assign the value to a hidden control.But in code behind i can't get the value of the hidden control. Please help me to get this.I tried more time.

```
Script
=======
<script type="text/javascript">
        function load_value() {
            var val = document.getElementById('<%= hf_xml.ClientID %>');
            val.value= "hai";//Whatever i want
            alert(val.value);//alert message show with text hai
        }
        window.onload = load_value;
    </script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_xml" runat="server" />

Code Behind
===========

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string value = hf_xml.Value;//Always Empty
 }
```

Comment: Change `val.value`, not `val.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing really missing/incorrect in your code. Try to understand the sequence of events that happen.

***[Window.Onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)*** is expected to get executed when the Page finishes loading. Whereas `Page_Load` is expected to be called earlier as the Page is still under process.

And this is indeed happening. As verified using debug symbols, the `Page_Load` is called first and the `window.onload` method will be called later. This is why your `HiddenField` is showing empty value.

Also, as expected, for the very first time when page is requested, HiddenField value will be Empty, but on next postback onwards, Value will be set for this HiddenField.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use innerHTML on `input` controls

Use `value` instead

```
var val = document.getElementById('<%= hf_xml.ClientID %>');
val.value = "hai";//Whatever i want
```

Comment: I used that but i can't get that

Comment: No error here. But in code behind page load i couldn't get the hf_xml value. It always return null

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to get the value before posting to server ?? means you cant access the value before posting to server(means on button click or some server side events)

put a asp:button on form and check the value after clicking the button